# How to import `block-ui`, `spectrum-colorpicker`, `sass.js` in typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

I use some plugins as `block-ui`, `spectrum-colorpicker`, `sass.js` ... in `angular2 + typescript` project.

For now I load them in index.html file. But I want import them and load when I need to use. I try to import with `import * as [Name] form '[plugin]'` or `import {default as [Name]} from '[plugin]'` an it don't work.

Could you please help me, how can I import them in my project? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> For now I load them in index.html file

You cannot use `import * from` style ES6 import syntax *natively* in the browser. Move the code into a `main.ts` and then load that file (e.g. if using systemjs `System.import` etc).